# Doing Layer stack in ERDAS Imagine

Tags: erdas-imagine, stack, image-analysis

I am trying to do "Layer Stack" of Landsat 5 Surface Reflectance image in ERDAS Imagine 2015 but every time i get output as black and white image. Though pixels have RGB  values but still getting my entire study area as white.

What can I do to correct this?

I already have installed Erdas two times after clearing cached data but could not get over this problem

[image].

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure Input and Output bit are same.